# Exporting a layer with one-to-many non-spatial relationships into GeoJSON

Tags: qgis, geojson, export

I have a ShapeFile (postcode areas) with a one-to-many relationship with a list of attributes (customers who fall within that postcode).

Is it possible in QGIS to export the ShapeFile to GeoJSON to include these relationships or will I need to directly manipulate the GeoJSON and add the data separately?

Comment: The relation is not stored in the shapefile, so I think that will not be exported to the GeoJSON. But maybe you can create a new joined layer with the [Join attributes by field value](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#join-attributes-by-field-value) tool and export the joinied laiyer.